# Unable to use package manager due to "exclusive lock" error

Tags: package-management, lock

My synaptic package manager in ubuntu is giving error:

```
  Unable to get exclusive lock
  This usually means that another package management application(like apt-get or  
  aptitude) is already running. Please close that application first.
```

Comment: The error message generally means that you can only have one "Package Manager" open at a time. That includes apt, aptitude, gdebi, synaptic, software centre etc. Close all the "Package Managers" and try Synaptic again. If you still get the message something more serious is happening"

Comment: So, this question may had similarities with the "Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?", but not any more. In the latest ubuntu  synaptic (though being the coolest ever imho) does not play well with "Software & Updates": When you go to the repositories option from inside synaptic, "Software & Updates" comes up allowing you to choose e.g. proprietary drivers, HOWEVER it cannot apply the changes because synaptics holds the lock. The only solution I found was to run "Software & Updates" directly, then close it and open synaptic

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem. This post helped however, the `pa aux` command and the `Kill` command were ineffective. `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock` seemed to work, and I followed it up by [another Linux post](http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?58173-package-manager-lock).

> 1. You need sudo rights, so the full command is:
>
>    ```
>    sudo dpkg --configure -a
>    ```
> 2. Try using Konsole terminal program instead. Make sure that all package managers are closed! Issue the commands:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get update  
>    sudo apt-get upgrade
>    ```

The `sudo apt-get update` command worked.

The `sudo apt-get upgrade` one did not as it stated `could not get dns proxy`.

Also the following came up:

```
some files failed to upload using old files.
```

At least the update was able to fetch 39 of them. The other is irrelevant as this is the latest Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

Comment: You've posted this as an answer, and it's perhaps an attempt to answer the question here. But if you want help with the problems you had, you should post a new question to ask for that. Also, please note that you probably should have run `ps aux` rather than `pa aux` and `kill` rather than `Kill`. Terminal commands don't have any tolerance for incorrect spelling or incorrect capitalization.

Answer (score 5):

I had interrupted a `sudo apt-get upgrade`, and I was unable to get a lock on anything. I simply fixed it by running `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, and it let me pick up where I left off. Dunno if it helps, might as well share.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the other answer, you have to make sure that no other package management software is running.

Open a terminal and type the following command

```
ps aux | grep program-name
```

where program-name can be apt, software etc. (just to find out if apt-get or Software Center are running). If you get entries for them, note down their process id. Let it be xxxx. Then give the following command.

```
kill xxxx
```

Now try opening synaptic.

If the problem still persists, give the following command in the terminal,

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Now synaptic should hopefully open.

Answer (score 2):

This error means that anoher Package Management Software is already running and using the files which for example contain the sources for the software. I would look for working processes like apt-get or aptitude with the system-monitor and exit them. Than restart synaptic and it should work.