# How can I update 12.04 without update manager?

Tags: 12.04, updates, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to use package manager due to “exclusive lock” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157196/unable-to-use-package-manager-due-to-exclusive-lock-error)

When I try to update Ubuntu - I know that I have 233 updates - I get this message every time:

```
Unable to get exclusive lock

This usually means that another package management application (like apt-get or aptitude) already running. 
Please close that application first.
```

And I don't find this application.

Answer (score 2):

It means there are other package management applications currently running e.g. Software Center, Synaptic, apt-get.

To make sure no other packaging management applications are running, open the terminal and run:

```
sudo killall -9 apt-get
```

then do another update by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If the problem persist, it's because the lock file still exist. You need to delete it by running this in the terminal:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Now try to update or upgrade again.

Comment: Peachy? When I try : sudo killall -9 apt-get; it says "apt-get no process found"

Answer (score 0):

Its mostly because software center, or synaptic or the two you mentioned are running. If you don't see any of those running, try restarting your PC and try to update it it. But the terminal way to update it is

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

Running `sudo apt-get update` will update the package lists (what packages can be updated, new packages etc), so you want to run that to find out what can be updated, and `sudo apt-get upgrade` to action the updates.

An all-in-one command for updating from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```