# Upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 loops and fails with "Unable to get exclusive lock"

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 but it consistently fails in the same way.

First, the upgrade process loops (do-release-upgrade) by going through the following many times

```
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done
```

Then it dies with "Unable to get exclusive lock".

I am not running another package manager, so this is not a duplicate of [Unable to use package manager due to "exclusive lock" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157196/unable-to-use-package-manager-due-to-exclusive-lock-error).

Anybody has any ideas how to go about fixing this? I tried looking at the logs in /var/log/dist-upgrade but I couldn't find any useful error information.

Comment: As you said, if you are sure that you don't have another package manager running have tried this as suugested in the case you mentioned: sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock and then rerun the upgrade?

Comment: @Mordoc There is something wrong with the release-upgrade, i've checked the lock and it is not there. I can do regular updates and install new packages no problem. I suspect the problem is related to the loop I mentioned, as if it is forking a dpkg process too many times until they eventually lock up and the process dies.

Comment: I would check around, because I believe at one time you could change the repository name from say precise to quantal to produce the same effect. The process was ensure that you updated everything in your current version with repo's and then switch them and run sudo apt-get dist-upgrade.

Comment: Interesting, I'll try it out <http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?59205-Way-to-upgrade-from-precise-pangolin-12-04-to-alpha-1>.

Comment: @mordoc It worked -- find/replace and dist-upgrade. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check around, because I believe at one time you could change the repository name from say precise to quantal to produce the same effect. The process was ensure that you updated everything in your current version with repo's and then switch them and run sudo apt-get dist-upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

Dropbox and Citrix ICA clients blocked my attempts at removing dpkg and apt processes.  I removed those two apps, THEN killed dpkg and apt processes, and the good ol'apt-get worked fine without the lock problem.

Comment: This is likely unrelated to OP's issue. It would also be good to describe in detail how you removed those two applications as low-quality answers will be deleted.